# ObjectDataSource RemoveByID not working, issue with DataKeyNames?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

Using ASP.NET/C#/nHibernate architecture - I have a `GridView` with an `ObjectDataSource` and am having problems getting the delete method to work.

When I simply use the `Remove(T entity)` function declared in my service layer (which then calls down to my nHibernate repository), the `GridView_RowDeleting()` method gets called, followed by `ObjectDataSource_Deleting()`, and then the service layer function is invoked and the business object is properly deleted.

However, when I try to use the `RemoveByID(int ID)` function, after the `GridView_RowDeleting()` and `ObjectDataSource_Deleting()` methods are called, the service layer is never being invoked.

I think this has something to do with the `ObjectDataSource.DeleteParameters`, but I can't seem to get it right.

Below is the code snippet for the GridView and ObjectDataSource.  As you can see, I have the business object's primary key `pkChapter7ID` listed in the GridView's `DataKeyNames`:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvChapter7" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsChapter7" DataKeyNames="pkChapter7ID">
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="pkChapter7ID" HeaderText="pkChapter7ID" SortExpression="pkChapter7ID"/>
      ...
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>

  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsChapter7" runat="server"
    DeleteMethod="RemoveByID" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    SelectMethod="FindAllForProjectID" TypeName="CLS.Services.Chapter7Service">
    <DeleteParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:SessionParameter Name="ID" SessionField="ProjectID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And the relevant portion of my generic service layer (calls down the nHibernate repository, which is working fine once I get there):

```
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, false)]
    public virtual void Remove(T entity)
    {
        _repository.Remove(entity);
    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)]
    public virtual void RemoveByID(int ID)
    {
        T entity = FindBy(ID);
        if (entity != null)
            _repository.Remove(entity);
    }
```

I have tried setting `DeleteParameters` in the _RowDeleting method:

```
protected void gvChapter7_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    odsChapter7.DeleteParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = e.Keys["pkChapter7ID"].ToString();
}
```

As well as numerous ways of setting up the ObjectDataSource control parameter in the aspx page, such as:

```
<DeleteParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvChapter7" Name="ID" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

Can anyone see what I am missing?